# Private docker registry folder structure

Tags: image, docker, docker-registry

I have setup a private registry for storing the internal images. I am wondering if there is a good guide on how the folder layout should be. I am thinking of something like:

```
Dev
Test
Prod
```

The idea being Dev is where the developers can push all their images, test is where the CI CD pipeline verified images will go and Prod is where images are promoted from test folder with a new tag.

Any suggestions from your experience on what is a good setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me recommend you use dev, test and prod as part of docker-registry name:

For example, if your registry is `docker-registry.<your_org>.ofi:5000/<product>`, you could use:

- docker-registry.(your_org).ofi:5000/dev
- docker-registry.(your_org).ofi:5000/test
- docker-registry.(your_org).ofi:5000/prod

After that, you can add versioned images to **docker-registry..ofi:5000/dev:yourimage-1.0**, for example.